# How do I print a number in assembly AT&T?

Tags: assembly, att

I am new in assembly and I want to print a value stored in a register with assembly AT&T.

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    mov $42, %edx

    # what should be here?

    mov $1, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

I found many "Hello, world" examples with section ".data" and `write` calls, but `write` accepts a string buffer, not an integer. What is the most elegant way to output the number in `%edx` into stdout?

Comment: What do you mean by "elegant"? Some would consider using years-verified code like `libc` and `printf`, others would write their own converter, and minority of people would use some high level programming language.

Comment: (seasoned assembly programmers usually don't bother and just check the value directly in register in debugger, outputting results is overrated)